# I want to alert all p elements' text (basic jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning JQuery. I'm a new Jquery Student as it is seen.

This is my html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jquery 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
        var num = 0;
        $("p").each(function(){
            var data = data + $(this:eq(num)).html();
            num =+1;
            });
        alert(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Deneme
    </p>
    <p>
        Deneme2
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to alert all p elements' text. This code not working..
How can i do?

Comment: When you say 'not working' - what does it do or not do? How is it not working?

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()` if you're just gathering text content. [Just use `$('p').text()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419966/i-want-to-alert-all-p-elements-text-basic-jquery/7420133#7420133)

Comment: Alright, I'll try not to be, but as long as I continue to exist, I will continue to be, as I can not be and not be at the same time and in the same manner. The only way I could manage to not be would be for me to not exist, which would bring this comment to an abrupt...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the code to this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var data = "";
    $("p").each(function(index, element) {   // note that the .each() handler has two parameters that can be used also
        data += $(this).html();              // "this" inside the .each() handler function is the current DOM element in the iteration
    });
    alert(data);
});
```

Inside the `.each()` handler function, the `this` value is the current DOM element in the iteration.  Also, the `.each()` handler has two parameters on it that can also be used.  `index` is where you are in the iteration (from 0 to length-1) and `element` is the current DOM element (same value as `this`).

You can read more about `.each()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: will +1 if you remove `index,element` serves no purpose here.

Comment: @f0x - I disagree that part of his example serves no purpose. For someone just getting to know jQuery's `.each()` method, it gives good insight into how parameters are passed. Some commenting could be helpful, though.

Comment: I put the index, element in there to show the OP that `each()` includes those two parameters since they clearly didn't know that based on their original code.  Just trying to teach them a bit more.  Those params are not needed here, but also doesn't cost anything - they are passed whether you declare them or not.

Comment: indeed, perhaps just a comment on their functions instead of random code not used is probably more harmful than explanatory.

Comment: @f0x - I guess I disagree that declaring those parameters are random code.  It's not random.  Those are the parameters that are ALWAYS passed to the `.each()` handler function.  They are always there whether you use them in a specific handler or not so declaring them is certainly not "random code".

Comment: to the OP it is because it has no baring on his "issue". Provide some insight to your bountiful knowledge.

Comment: Added a comment to the code related to the `index` and `element` params.

Comment: +1 perhaps a link to `context` would've been grand but alas, another subject ;)

Comment: @jfriend00 I am trying to find out 1st and 3rd p tags using [`jQuery :nth-of-type() Selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthoftype.asp). I need to validate first p tag and then update the 3rd one. [Can you advice here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30391360/2061309)?

Answer (score 5):

There is multiple small problems:

- First, declare you `data` variable outside of the callback function, else the variable is only visible inside of the function itself.
- replace `$(this:eq(num))` by `$(this)`. In jQuery.each's callback, `this` is the current element.
- you don't need the `num` variable

  ```
  $("document").ready(function(){
      var data = ''; // data will be visible from inside of the inner function:
      $("p").each(function(){
          data += $(this).html(); // `this` is the current element
      });
      alert(data);
  });
  ```

**Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DBme5/**

Comment: Okey thank you. If I want to write this data to other <p> elements, how can i do? I'm asking for learning.. :)

Comment: $(the_other_element).html(data), or $(the_other_element).text(data)

Comment: No :) I didn't say this. I will create new <p> element and write <p> element's inside.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var data = "";
        $("p").each(function(){
            data += $(this).text();
        });
        alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

may be not just this ?

```
$("p").each(function(){
   alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors on your code

```
$(this:eq(num)).html(); // $(this) already refers to the current element,
                        // so $(this).html() is enough

num =+1; // should be: num += 1
```

This is a correct version

```
var data = '';

$( 'p' ).each( function () {

    data += $( this ).html();

});
```

And here's a solution with plain JavaScript

```
var data = '',
    elements = document.getElementsByTagName( 'p' );

for ( var x = 0, len = elements.length; x < len; x += 1 )
{
    data += elements[x].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `.each()` at all if you just have (or want) text content.

```
alert( $('p').text() );
```

jQuery will concatenate it for you.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8apPN/

---

If there is nested HTML markup that you want to display, then do this instead:

```
var html = $.map( $('p'), function(v) { return v.innerHTML; }).join('');

alert( html );
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8apPN/1/